# How to create high-quality jpg from pdf in Acrobat Pro DC?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I need to a) **rasterize** and b) **convert from CMYK to RGB** a lot of pdfs, to make them work with the Flip book plugin on our homepage.

The method I have used is Save as - jpg; then Combine files (selecting all the jpgs, save as a new pdf).

The images look good, but my issue is that text gets really ugly, like this:

[image: this is one sample]

This happens when I save as jpg. All settings in the Save as dialog are set to max, but that seem to affect only the images. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that the font you are really using? It looks like a generic font.

Well lets think it is. The problem I see is an aliasing problem.

One option is that you double the resolution (or 4x) on the export to the jpg, then resample the images with a bicubic algorithm, and then save your pdf again.

Probably it is a good idea to use PNG like John comented. But the main problem is the non aliased output.